# What is the answer? Amount or Quantity or Number

Tags: british-english

- Try to reduce the .......... of cups of tea you drink a day
  (amount - Quantity - Number)
  Some help please

Comment: The latter two are both acceptable usages. You could say "Try to reduce the amount of tea you drink a day" as well, as "tea" is not countable.

Comment: In general, if you have "of cups" in there then a count is implied and "number" is most appropriate.  Drop "of cups" and "amount" or "quantity" would be more appropriate.

Comment: From now on I am asking every question, here and _i.r.l._, as simply _What is the answer?_

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if you want the American answer, but an amount is always preceded by a currency symbol, such as a dollar sign.  A quantity is followed by a unit of measure, such as a gallon.  For the people who make coffeemakers, 1 cup equals 4 ounces.  For British tea drinkers, probably not.

Comment: "Amount " can certainly be used for non-currency things - the amount of evidence, the amount of gasoline.

Comment: American dictionaries disagree with this answer.